# What is the purpose of bootstrap in a default MVC5 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry for the rookie question. However, if I create a brand new MVC5 project in VS2013 and basically choose the defaults, it comes "out of the box" with bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js already referenced in the project.

I've recently become familiar with bootstrap as being useful for modals. Also, if I inspect the element upon running the project, I can see that bootstrap.css styles are being used (much more so than site.css). Yet, I see nothing that would warrant the bootstrap.js file being referenced too.

So, the question is somewhat three-part (but any reasonable explanation will do):

1. Is there some magic happening there that would warrant bootstrap.js being there straight out of the box? In other words, is bootstrap.js being used for something I'm not seeing?
2. If the answer to question one (in any sense) is "No," then why are the default styles primarily bootstrap.css? (i.e. What is so good about them?)
3. If there is no good explanation for questions 1 & 2, then why is bootstrap there by default? Do they just assume you will want it?

I like to think most things Microsoft are calculated, so I just feel like I'm not seeing the full picture regarding why bootstrap is there by default. Any light shedding is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could of course write your own `css` from scratch or use one that has been tested and known to be cross browser friendly - the choice is yours. Just remove them if you don't want them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, bootstrap.js is only required if you want to use one of the additional plugins which require JavaScript to function. You can see these here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/
2. The default styles are bootstrap.css as this gives you a responsive CSS framework to work with out-of-the-box. Bootstrap is the most widely used framework which the majority of web developers are experienced with. There's also lots of re-useable themes and templates available online, have a look at https://bootswatch.com/ or http://www.bootstrapzero.com/ or http://startbootstrap.com/
3. Hopefully 1 & 2 answer your question. I believe Microsoft chose to include Boostrap by default as it's easy to use, has a low barrier to entry and gives you a lot of nice features with minimal effort.

That being said, you definitely don't have to use it. If you want to go down another path simply remove the CSS and JS references and NuGet packages and you're good to go. Nothing else will be affected, there's no "magic" happening as you put it :)

Comment: Both great answers, but I think this one gave me my eureka moment. I had no idea bootstrap was so widely used or that the default theme was responsive. Plus, I appreciate the extra links and such. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is just for convenience. 
It is always a good thing to not start blank and empty.

So I guess Microsoft made the decision to deliver ASP.NET MVC Templates with a widly used CSS framework to help you jumpstart very quickly.

Bootstrap.js is just some Javascript that helps you archive the visual appearance and effects that plain css ist no capable of.

I think for large applications you might want to rethink structure and frameworks (and Versioning) anyway. But for small starts that is certainly helpful.
But you can also start with a blank solution on your own and think about NuGet that helps you to pull in other frameworks, library and components as required.

HTH